# Parameter ignored when quoted

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting

I have a directory with 3 files: `file1`, `file2` and the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

Command="ls -1 -I file1"
echo "Command: $Command"

Files=`$Command`
echo "Files:"
echo $Files
```

The result is as one would expect. I.e. `file1` is ignored an not displayed in the listing:

```
$ ./test.sh
Command: ls -1 -I file1
Files:
file2
test.sh
```

Now, what if I wanted to support ignoring files with a space in the name? I should enclose the file name in quotes, right? Well...

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

Command="ls -1 -I 'file1'"
echo "Command: $Command"

Files=`$Command`
echo "Files:"
echo $Files
```

yields:

```
$ ./test.sh
Command: ls -1 -I 'file1'
Files:
file1
file2
test.sh
```

However, evaluating the same command directly in bash yields correctly:

```
$ ls -1 -I 'file1'
file2
test.sh
```

What is going on here? Adding quotes seems to throw something off track, but why?

It doesn't help to replace the command with anything of the sort:

```
Command="ls -1 -I \"file1\""
Command="ls -1 --ignore='file1'"
```

Nor does it help to change the evaluation of the command:

```
Files=$($Command)
Files=$(`echo $Command`)
```

It seems the correct behavior can only be recovered by introducing an `eval`

```
Files=$(eval $Command)
Files=`eval $Command`
```

I'm really curious to understand why `ls` is evaluated and executed, but somehow the quoted arguments to it are ignored, unless `eval` is added.

Comment: Did you post the exact interaction that you saw? `echo $Files` displaying more than one line of output seems strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [quote removal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_07) will not be applied to quote characters if they have themselves been quoted.

In:

```
Command="ls -1 -I 'file1'"
```

The single quote `'` was quoted by double quote `"`, so it's considered a part of string. You can use `printf` with `%q` (in `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`) to check:

```
$ printf '%q\n' "$Command"
ls -1 -I 'file1'
```

If you run directly in terminal, the single quote was not quoted, and was removed by the shell.